# How to add a value to json payload in clojure script

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I was trying to add a value to the json payload. Here is the actual payload in CLJS

```
//page-data payload
{
    "title": "Test page",
    "type": "page",
    "version": {
        "number": 12
    },
    "body": {
        "doc_format": {
            "value": "{\"type\":\"doc\",\"content\":[{\"type\":\"paragraph\",\"content\":[{\"text\":\"Updated by API\",\"type\":\"text\"}]}],\"version\":1}",
            "representation": "doc_format"
        }
    },
    "metadata": {
        "properties": {
            "editor": {.     // This is the one I was trying to add
                "key": "editor",
                "value": "v1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is code snippet trying to add but not working

```
(let [editversion {:key "editor" :value "v1"}]
        (->
          (http/request
            (assoc request
              ::http/endpoint (str "/xxx/xxx/xxx" (:id page-data)) // page-data is the cljs data structure
              ::http/method :put
              ::http/data
                (->
                  page-data
                  (select-keys [:title :type :body :metadata])
                  (assoc :version new-page-version)
                  (assoc-in [:body constants/page-content-format :value] (utils/clj->json new-body-value))
                  (assoc-in [:metadata :properties :editor] editversion) // This is the line trying to set editor value
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

What I am missing? your help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Is the code causing an error or exception?  If so, please show the exception.  Is the code returning a result that you do not expect?  If so, please show us the expected and actual results.

Comment: The comment chars of "//" seem to be for JavaScript, not ClojureScript.

Comment: I don't know if it is just a typo, but it seems there is an extra period just after the open brace on the line which has "editor" in the first snippet showing the page-data payload.

Answer (score 0):

Problem #0: Please update your question with the expected output.

Problem #1:

The expression `(:id page-data)` means "pull out the `:id` field from `page-data`".  However, there is no `:id` field in the map.

Problem #2:  What is `new-page-version`?

Then, repeat #0.

Please also see this list of [Clojure Documentation resources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be a comment on the question.

Comment: Ideally, sure. But it's too long to fit into a comment, and it has multiple parts. The original idea was to update the answer after he updated the question, but it appears to be abandoned now.